# How much kale is a "bunch?"

Tags: measurements

The recipes I find for kale chips all call for a "bunch" of kale. Volumes and/or weights of seasonings, etc. are given, but the amount of kale seems to be up to the vendor (or, in my case, the gardener). Can anyone point me to a reference indicating a measured quantity for a "bunch" of kale?

Answer (score 2):

Google returns some links saying that it is around 7 ounces.

I'd say a big handful of chopped kale would be about it.

But in the case of Kale Chips, you can make as much or as little as you want.